# How do I construct "going back to [verb]" type of sentence?

Tags: syntax, phrases

I feel really frustrated that I can't get a simple sentence like this correctly. I want to say, "are you going back to sleep?" My first thought was that I needed 戻る in the sentence, so I thought make I can just combine to verbs and it would magically mean what I expect it to mean such as ねって戻りますか？ I clearly have an misunderstanding of how 戻る can be applied. Could someone explain the thought process for arrive at the correct sentence?

Answer (score 2):

You can use (conjunctive form)に 戻る, that is, ねに 戻る.